# HP Printer: power light off, attention light on

Tags: printer, inkjet-printer

I have an HP Deskjet Ink Advantage 2010 that fails to turn on.

When I plug it in, the power light stays off, but the attention light is on. (Not blinking, but continuously on).

Nothing happens when I press the power button.

All the troubleshooting solutions on HP's web site involve a *blinking* attention light.

Comment: Then clearly no one but an HP engineer can help you.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams that's a shame though, I was expecting solutions.